# $E+F=E\oplus F \Leftarrow \bigcap$ of their bases $=∅$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand this theorem:

I will traduce it literally from my lecture notes:

> Given n≥1 subspaces $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ of a vector space V and considering the subspace $F=E_1+E_2+...+E_n$ if $B_1,B_2,...,B_n$ are bases of $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ and $B_i \cap B_j=∅ $ for every $i,j$ where i is not equal to j  so F is a direct sum of subspaces $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ and they are indipendent.

The question is:

- How can this theorem be dimostrated?

Comment: Do you mean 'basis' instead of 'base'?  If so, and if by $B_i$ you mean some finite set of vectors which form a basis of $E_i$, then the 'theorem' is not true.

Comment: That's wrong. Let $E_1 = \langle e_1\rangle$, $E_2 = \langle e_2 \rangle$ and $E_3 = \langle e_1 + e_2 \rangle$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th standard unit vector in $\mathbb R^2$. Any two bases of the $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint, but their sum is not direct.

Comment: you're right, I'm not English, so is a "translation mistake"

Comment: Have you tried showing it for just two subspaces first?

Comment: It's impossible to prove the theorem, because it's false.

Comment: Dear newbie, as a completely non-mathematical aside, how come you know the expression *newbie* which I would have supposed is not taught in English courses for foreigners ?(Please excuse this linguistic question: if you don't feel like answering it,  I'll immediately delete it)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg There's a variant of *newbie*, namely *noob*, that any guy younger than 30 knows, so it's not surprising that he knows the word.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's like Git Gud said, it's a common word.     I've tried to fix it, does it make sense now?

Comment: Dear newbie and @GitGud, thanks a lot for answering my  question. I'm over 30 and I know the words *newbie* and *noob*. The point is that when *I* learned English, my BBC books and records taught a rather formal kind of English which certainly excluded *newbie* (or a corresponding informal word which would have been popular at the time). This confirms that teaching is different nowadays. Another aspect is that I never met young anglophones while self-studying English, and this may be different for newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would indeed be a useful fact in exercises, if it were true. But it isn't.

Consider $E_1=\langle(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle$ and $E_2=\langle(1,1,0),(-1,1,0)\rangle$ as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's easy to show that
$B_1=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ and $B_2=\{(1,1,0),(-1,1,0)\}$ are bases of $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively. Also $B_1\cap B_2=\emptyset$.

However the sum of $E_1$ and $E_2$ is not direct, for the simple reason that $E_1=E_2$.

---

The simplest counterexample is, of course, $B_1=\{1\}$ and $B_2=\{2\}$, in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I've made an edit, written like it is written in my lecture, now does it make sense?

Comment: @newbie It's as false as before the edit.